# how make folders base on value of rows

Tags: excel, vba

firstly i want  to  write a macro for going through of every row  so if valuse of item  is more than 10 creat a folder base on values of that rows.in addition without  a duplicate folder !
for example if there is item20 then create a folder with this name 20_NT25153_29.9  then another rows

i wanna to add this sentence ,i know my code is very simple but i am new in VBA hence need  more help :)

[image: my sample]

```
 Sub loopthrough()

    With Worksheets("Output_" & Date)
      fName5 = .Range("d").Value
      fName1 = .Range("B").Value
      fName2 = .Range("c").Value
      fName4 = "_"
      BrowseForFolder = CurDir()
    End With

    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      If cell.Range("B").Value > "10" Then
          BrowseForFolder1 = BrowseForFolder & "\" & fName1 & fName2 & fName5
          MkDir BrowseForFolder1
      End If
    Next cell

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim sPath As String, sNewFolder As String

sPath = CurDir()
lLastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lLastRow
    If Range("B" & i).Value > 10 Then
        sNewFolder = Range("B" & i).Value & "_" & Range("C" & i).Value & "_" & Range("D" & i).Value
        If Dir(sPath & "\" & sNewFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MkDir (sPath & "\" & sNewFolder)
        End If
    End If
    sNewFolder = vbNullString
Next

End Sub
```

Fisrt of all I check for the last row index based on A column, not to loop through whole worksheet.
In a loop I've used a Dir() function with vbDirectory parameter which returns empty string when folder does not exists & in that case it creates a folder.

Comment: thank you for your respond,but it didnt work without any errors :(

Comment: i have another question, i use this code and works properly but it makes for every rows a folder , is it possible to make one folder for every same item for example in table i have two rows that item = 10 i need just first rows for every item , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

Folder name is column B value _ column C value _ column D value ?

```
Sub loopthrough()

Dim cell As Range, fName4

BrowseForFolder = CurDir()
fName4 = "_"

With Worksheets("Output_" & Date)
    For Each cell In .Range("B1", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If cell.Value > 10 Then
            BrowseForFolder1 = BrowseForFolder & "\" & cell.Value & fName4 & cell.Offset(, 1).Value & fName4 & cell.Offset(, 2).Value
            MkDir BrowseForFolder1
        End If
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for somebody need same as me

```
 Sub Macro1()

Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim sPath As String, sNewFolder As String

sPath = CurDir()
lLastRow =        workbooks(sFilename).Sheets(1).Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Workbooks(sFilename).Sheets(1).Activate

For i = 2 To lLastRow
If Workbooks(sFilename).Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value >= 10 Then
    sNewFolder = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value & "_" & ActiveSheet.Range("C" & 
               i ).Value & "_" & ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i).Value
     If Dir(sPath & "\" & sNewFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir (sPath & "\" & sNewFolder)
    End If
  End If
  sNewFolder = vbNullString
 Next

 End Sub
```